# Bash script to extract date/time from line in log file

Tags: bash, shell

I am seeking help to write a script that will get the last line from a log file and obtain the date/time entry of the last line. Then do a comparison from the current date/time to that of the date/time from the last line in the file. If the time difference is different by 60 minutes the report the process as failed, ie error code 1.

The log file format is:

```
Feb 11 16:46:01 [8064][8082] ssnotify.cpp:442:Send(): Send notification by mail: EvtType[5] SenderType[0] SenderName[Landing]    
Feb 11 16:50:52 [8064][8081] ssnotify.cpp:442:Send(): Send notification by mail: EvtType[5] SenderType[0] SenderName[Landing]    
Feb 11 17:07:56 [8064][8082] ssnotify.cpp:442:Send(): Send notification by mail: EvtType[5] SenderType[0] SenderName[Landing]    
Feb 11 17:13:58 [8064][8082] ssnotify.cpp:442:Send(): Send notification by mail: EvtType[5] SenderType[0] SenderName[Landing]
```

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: I haven't tried, I have googled, but cannot figure it out. I am very new to scripting/linux

Comment: You have too many questions rolled into one. You should split them individually, like "how to get the time from the file", "how to compare times in Bash" and finally "how to exit a process with an error code in Bash".

Answer (score 1):

Use `tail -1` to get the last line, then use `awk` to extract the third column (which contains the date):

```
tail -1 your_file | awk '{print $3}'
```